# Javascript - Move Square In A Circular Motion After Keypress

Tags: javascript, html, css, math, browser

Context:
In a simple javascript game i am designing, the player presses the arrow keys to move 4 different squares around the perimeter of a circle. The squares are all equally spaced from each other. To visually see what I am talking about, I included a picture of the setup.

Issue:
My problem is that I am unsure of how to make the equation cognizant of the current x and y position of the square. The equation has to be able to move the square both forwards and backwards around the perimeter. My current code is down below, any help is appreciated!

```
function movefunction() {
t += 1;
var r = 150;

newLeft = Math.floor((r * Math.sin(t)));
newTop = Math.floor((r * Math.cos(t)));

circ1.style.left = parseInt(circ1.style.left) + newLeft + 'px'
circ1.style.top = parseInt(circ1.style.left) + newTop + 'px'
}
```

[image]